# Given $(\{1, 3, 5, 15, 25, 33, 55, 99, 165\},\mid)$ find notable elements of $\{5, 15, 25, 33\}$

Tags: relations, solution-verification

> Given $$(A=\{1, 3, 5, 15, 25, 33, 55, 99, 165\},\mid)\colon$$
>
> 1. Make the Hasse Diagram.
> 2. Given $B=\{5, 15, 25, 33\}\subseteq A$ find maximals, minimals, lower and upper bound sets, infimum, supremum and indicate (if exist) maximum and/or minimum.

---

1. The Hasse Diagram is:

   [image: Hasse Diagram]
2. We draw $B$:

   [image: Set B]

   - Maximals of $B$: $15,25,33$.
   - Minimals of $B$: $5$.
   - Lower bound set: $\{1\}$.
   - Upper bound set: $\{99,165\}$.
   - Infimum: $1$.
   - Maximum: $165$.
   - Minimum: $5$.

Is it correct? Please ask me any definition that you don't understand/have.

Comment: There is no maximum or minimum of $B.$ A maximum is an element of $B$ that is divisible by every element of $B.$ Also, $33$ is both a maximal and minimal element of $B.$

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndrews! What about the lower and upper bound sets?

Comment: Don’t know the definition for lower or upper bound sets, sorry.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_and_lower_bounds Now? Thank you.